Rotate sprites in Autodesk Viewer
I am implementing a solution that allows me to create points (sprites) in a pdf in the Autodesk viewer.
For this I am using the DataVisualization extension.
But the problem is that when creating the sprite, I can't rotate it.
Does anyone know a way to rotate these sprites?
I need the sprite to rotate to direct it to the area I want to point to

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I'm afraid the Data Visualization extension doesn't support rotating sprites. What you could do instead is, add custom HTML or SVG elements on top of the Viewer canvas, and use the Viewer SDK to make sure these elements stay "attached" to a specific XYZ position in the model space. We do this in the APS Digital Twin demo:

